# Signed abc.pkg passes spctl control and fails check-signature control. Consequences of the check-signature tool failure?

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite, code-signing, osx-gatekeeper

We have created an abc.pkg installer which contains two different packages; a def.mpkg(bundle style) and a ghi.pkg(flat package). The installer supports OS version 10.5 and above. 
We have digitally signed the abc.pkg installer and based on [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2206/_index.html) we simulated Gatekeeper's behavior.

The signed abc.pkg passes the spctl control:

```
spctl -a -v --type install abc.pkg
```

returns:

```
abc.pkg:accepted
source: Developer ID
```

which based on the documentation mentioned previously means that  Gatekeeper will accept our package's signature, but fails the check-signature control:

```
./check-signature ~/path_to_the_installer/abc.pkg
```

returns:

```
(c) 2014 Apple Inc. All rights reserved.
/path_to_the_installer/abc.pkg: code object is not signed at all
NO
```

which means that the signature doesn't meet Gatekeeper requirements.

We have tested abc.pkg installer on a Mac OS X 10.6 and on a Mac OS X 10.10 and the installation was successful both times.

What exactly means that abc.pkg doesn't meet Gatekeeper's requirements and which are the consequences of the check-signature tool failure?

Shouldn't we see Apple's warning:

> "abc.pkg" is from an unidentified developer. Are you sure you want to
>   open it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the verbose option of check-signature to get more information; it should tell you what bit of the signature is unacceptable. I was having an issue where both spctl and check-signature would pass, but the app would still fail to launch. Using OSX's console, you can see a system message posted when the app/package fails to launch to determine the exact cause of the failure.

In my case the issue was that the app trying to load a library that was unsigned, outside of its resources, and therefore rejected. I used the terminal otool command to check dependencies, and the install_name_tool to redirect any libraries that were referencing an external library. I had a signed version of the library in the app's resources, and once I redirected the reference to it, the app opened without a hitch.